# Why isn't fade div to black on scroll working?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, fade

I've attempted to create a fade to black with scrollY and simple query selectors, cannot for the life of me work out why it might not be functioning?
It should be a simple case of bringing down the l value of the background color hsl to 0, here's my code:

```
const lightness = 100;
const body = document.querySelector('.body')

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const y = window.scrollY
  newLightness = (lightness - y/10)
  if (newLightness < 0) {
    newLightness = 0;
  }
  body.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(0, 0, ${newLightness})`
})
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the percent signs?  See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_hsl.asp

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

1. `document.querySelector('body')` : If you use `.body` you are searching for a the **first** element with the class name body. For tags like div/body/span etc. you can simply use the tag name without any symbol.
2. In `hsl`, saturation and lightness are in %;

```
let lightness = 100;
const body = document.querySelector('body')

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const y = window.scrollY
  let newLightness = (lightness - y/10) //Added the let keyword
  if (newLightness < 0) {
    newLightness = 0;
  }
  body.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(0, 0%, ${newLightness}%)`
})
```

Also, good practice to declare your variables with let/var etc. based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

You were super close. Firstly, I'd like to say ensure that your body tag does in fact have `class="body"` on it as your querySelector is looking for class. Secondly, the second and third arguments in the `hsl()` value need to be followed with the percentage symbol...

body.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(0, 0%, ${newLightness}%)`

Comment: yep class="body" etc, still no luck. I've definitely achieved this with RGB values before, it wouldn't be an issue with using HSL for this would it?

Comment: do you have another `scroll eventListener` on your window defined above this one?